# Saved LDAP Query Locked Out Specific OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

Currently I can do this in powershell via this script:

```
Search-ADAccount –LockedOut -SearchBase 'OU=location,OU=country,DC=company,DC=com' | ft Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate
```

I would rather have it in a LDAP saved query, I found this one to display all locked out accounts in the company:

```
(&(&(ObjectCategory=Person)(ObjectClass=User)(LockoutTime>=1)))
```

I have tried a number of combinations, but I can't seem to get it right. Here is one of them:

```
(&(&(ObjectCategory=Person)(ObjectClass=User)(memberof=OU=location,OU=country,DC=company,DC=com)(LockoutTime>=1)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As information, when you create a new query, you have the option of specifying the "query root"... by drilling down with that, I was able to achieve the desired goal. I didn't have to modify the query string at all.

Comment: Yes, MemberOf is for members in a group, not children of an OU.